# How to infer state space parameters from an LSTM model?

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, lstm, state-space-models

I'm attempting to create a state-space model by training my time series data with an LSTM.  I'm hoping the LSTM will capture non-linear phenomenon as opposed to a linear state-space model.  The only problem is that while a state-space model has interpretative parameters like the state and observation matrix, an LSTM doesn't have that.  Does anyone know how to get these types of matrices from an LSTM, whether through Monte Carlo sampling or other means?

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question, but it is advanced topic that still hasn't been solved completely by researchers in the field. Some teams have tried to obtain representations of the embeddings after an LSTM is trained on time series data.

The only published paper I've seen so far is [this one](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1709.01907.pdf).

You might want too look at how people extract language embeddings from translation and speech recognition seq2seq models and then see if the same method can be used for time series applications.